# Django: Sharing the same queue in different modules

Tags: python, django, queue, python-multithreading

Before all, I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705408/sharing-a-queue-instance-between-different-modules) and this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586233/sharing-queue-between-threads-running-in-different-modules), none of them helped.
I'm working on django, and i have a thread running as a daemon, it keeps waiting for data to be put in a queue, to work on it.

package1/workers.py

```
from package1 import queue

class Worker(Thread):


    def run(self) -> None:
        print("worker started")
        while True:
            print("before blocking")
            print(queue)
            meta_data = queue.get()
            print("data received")            
            queue.task_done()
```

both of the queue and the worker thread are declared in the **init**.py, like so:

package1/**init**.py

```
import os
from queue import Queue

queue = Queue()

def prepare_workers():
    from package1.workers import Worker

    worker = Worker(daemon=True)
    worker.start()


if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN', None) != 'true': # a work around to avoid the appRegistery not ready yet exception...
    prepare_workers()
```

and in the models package, i'm receiving a signal to put data in the queue, like so:

package1/models.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=AModel)
def a_model_created_signal(sender, instance, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if created and not raw:
        from package1 import queue
        meta_data = some_data_here
        print(queue)
        queue.put(meta_data)
        print('data put')
```

this is the console output:

```
(venv) C:\path_to_project>py manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
worker started
before blocking
<queue.Queue object at 0x000001C7A0C80160>
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 23, 2020 - 18:41:46
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'dictili.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:80/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
<queue.Queue object at 0x00000212F18D6D68>
data put
```

as you can see the signal is being received and the data is being put, but the queue objects are in different memory locations, which means they are not the same.
I have tried other solutions like declaring the queue inside the worker like a static variable, and some other tricks that I found here and there, but nothing seems to work.
any help or guidance is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: queues has different ids, which means it initialized twice

Comment: @minglyu yes i know!